# Complex constant i in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, std, complex-numbers

When writing C++ code, rather than:

```
double a, b;
...
std::complex<double> z = a + b * std::complex<double>(0, 1);
```

I would prefer to write something like:

```
std::complex<double> z = a + b * i;
```

I can see that C99 has macro `I` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/I), but it can't be use with `std::complex`:

```
std::complex<double> z = a + b * I; // does not compile
```

Of course, I could define myself some constant for that purpose, but that constant must exist somewhere already in C++. What is it called?

Comment: @KamilCuk you can't do that. C++ doesn't support C's `_Complex` type and use `std::complex` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The custom literal `i` (e.g. `1i`), see example in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std::complex_literals;
std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since C++14, you can use the [complex literal `""i`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator%22%22i) to specify (only) the imaginary part of a complex number. Thus, for *i* you can use `1i`.