# How do you access the imaginary unit without "using namespace std::complex_literals"?

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, complex-numbers, std

I am currently working with complex numbers. I need something to represent the imaginary unit. One way to do that would be to define a variable

```
std::complex<double> imaginary_unit{0, 1};
```

However, I have found that there is a built in imaginary unit `i`. This unit is discussed, for example, in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68588726/complex-constant-i-in-c).

The suggested solution is the following:

```
#include <complex>
using namespace std::complex_literals;
```

and then to use the constant `i` like below:

```
std::complex<double> z1 = 1i * 1i;
```

I have been taught that `using namespace` is bad style and can create problems for people that use my headers. I have tried to access this built in constant `i` in a verbose way, but so far I haven't succeeded. Two failed examples are below:

```
// error: namespace std::literals::complex_literals has no member i
std::literals::complex_literals::i
```

```
// error: more than one instance of overloaded function
std::literals::complex_literals::operator""i(3.0)
```

How do I access the constant `i` without defining my own `i` or `using namespace`?

Comment: `using std::complex_literals::i;`?

Comment: Note that `i` isn't actually a constant here, it's a [user-defined literal operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal). So you could use `using std::complex_literals::operator""i;` and then you could write `3.0i`.

Comment: Is such really needed in a header? If one could push that out..

Comment: Somewhat confusing - why are you pursuing `std::literals::complex_literals::operator""i(3.0) ` over the already-working `std::complex<double>{0.0,3.0}`?

Comment: Don't put put the using directive in a place that pollutes the global namespace? This sort of adherence to guidelines without regard to context is cargo cult programming.

Comment: `std::complex_literals` is an incredibly small namespace. It's nothing like `using namespace anything_else;`. For the record, user code can't even define this operator literal so there's no chance of this clashing with any user code.

Comment: accidentally polluting the namespace with ```i``` when that is the go-to dummy variable in for loops seems like a bad idea in the long run

Comment: @user542101, That's not how it works, the name of this is `operator""i`.

Answer (score 2):

You could create your unit constant like this:

```
constexpr auto imaginary_unit = std::literals::complex_literals::operator""i(1.L);
```

... but if you don't use the literal namespace, `std::complex<double> imaginary_unit{0, 1};` is preferable. It's shorter and easier to read.

> ... the constant `i` ...

`i` is not a constant. It's a user-defined literal. One possible implementation:

```
constexpr std::complex<double> operator""i(long double d) {
    return std::complex<double>{0.0, static_cast<double>(d)};
}
```

I don't think you should be afraid of `using` the literal namespaces. They are there to simplify life.

Comment: How would you do something like ```std::literals::complex_literals::operator""i(1.L);``` with a ```double``` instead of ```1.L```?

Comment: @user542101 I don't think you can. It needs a `long double` or `unsigned long long`. It'll create a `std::complex<double>` out of it though.